# mysqli_fetch_array with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysqli

How do i get `mysqli_fetch_array` with prepared statements? i tried `fetch_assoc()` but i always get an error telling me that `fetch_assoc()` is not defined. How do i make it work?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE 
            username = ? AND 
            pass = ? LIMIT 1";

$stmt = $_SESSION['connessione']->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();

if($stmt->num_rows == 1){
    $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
    // originally it was like this $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    // where $result was the query result
    $this->login_iduser = $row['id'];
    $this->login_profile_pic = $row['pic'];
    $this->login_privileges = $row['admin'];
    return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

As you can see above i need to find the `$row` array.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to have [MySQLND](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) installed to do this. `mysqli` prepared statements don't result a `mysqli_result` object natively. You'll need to use [get_result](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
if($result->num_rows == 1){
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```